Uploading files in Remix gives me a file return type of application/octet-stream
I am following the remix guide on how to upload files from a form. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/unstable-create-file-upload-handler.
In my action I have a file uploader that looks like so,
  const uploadHandler = unstable_composeUploadHandlers(
    unstable_createFileUploadHandler({
      // Limit file upload to csv file
      filter: ({ contentType }) => contentType.includes('text/csv'),
      // Store the email files in the correct folder
      directory: './public/files',
      // By default, `unstable_createFileUploadHandler` adds a number to the file
      // names if there's another with the same name; by disabling it, we replace
      // the old file
      avoidFileConflicts: false,
      // Use the actual filename as the final filename
      file: ({ filename }) => filename,
    }),
    unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler(),
  );

const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(request, uploadHandler);


const file = formData.get('file')
const userField = formData.get('user_field');
console.log(userField);
console.log(file);

When I console log my values userField look correct but file is a type Blob { size: 0, type: 'application/octet-stream' }. However, when I remove unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler from the upload handler it correctly returns a type of NodeOnDiskFile but then userField is null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
